# How to convert MIPS instructions to machine code?

Tags: assembly, mips, machine-code, instruction-set

I'm stuck at converting the below MIPS instruction to machine code

```
  sb $t3, 40($s2)
  beq $s0, $s1, Lab1
  j Lab1

  jr $s0
```

So far, I have

```
101000  10010       01011       101000
000100  10000       10001       0x00400000
```

How do I go from here? Since 0x00400000 is address not value, I don't think I translate it into binary. And so on...  I can't really find an example to go on from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I think I'm getting a better idea now by looking at [MIPS: Calculating BEQ into Hexadecimal Machine Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21802457/mips-calculating-beq-into-hexadecimal-machine-code) and Lưu's answer.

```
  beq $s0, $s1, Lab1
=>000100 10000 10001 0x00400000
=>0001 0010 0001 0001 (0x004000040 + 1 away instruction)
=>0001 0010 0001 0001 0000 0000 0000 0101
=12110001
  j Lab1
=>0000 1000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
=08100000
  jr $s0
=>0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000
=02000008
```

So this is what I got. If any error please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The encoding depends on the instruction type.

For *relative branch* like `beq`, the immediate is the offset so you need to specify the distance between the current instruction and the branch target. For example to skip next 3 instructions you need `beq $s0, $s1, +3` which encodes as

```
opcode      $s0      $s1                     +3
000100    10000    10001    0000 0000 0000 0011
```

For *absolute jump* you need to make sure that the target and the current instruction's high 6 bits are the same. The immediate address is the target's low 26 bits shifted by 2. The j instruction's format is `0000 10ii iiii iiii iiii iiii iiii iiii` so `j 0x00400000` will be encoded as

```
0000 1000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

You can read more about the encoding in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6950230/995714) as well as the courses here:

- http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/addr.html
- http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/jump.html

The instruction encoding is also available [here](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html)

But why do you use both conditional branch and jump to `Lab1` right beside each other? It's useless because eventually it will jump without doing anything

Comment: It is assigned by prof. He probably made it for the sake of having students to know what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Immediate values in MIPS instructions are encoded directly as their binary representations.

Comment: How can I do that when 0x00400000 is represented 010000000000000000000000 (24 bits) when in I-type it should be 16? how do I compress it?

Comment: If ``0x00400000`` represents the address of ``Lab1``, then you need to  encode the number of instructions that you want to jump over, which I believe is just ``address of target instruction - address of branch instruction - 1``, but I might be wrong about that. However, if ``0x00400000`` already represents that jump, then it's not possible, and your code needs to be adjusted

Comment: Actually, on reflection I realized that it would be possible to assemble if ``0x00400000`` was an offset, but it would require adding additional instructions to jump farther than 16 bits would normally allow